# Prevent headphones from waking up my macbook

Tags: macos, bluetooth, macbook

I have a MacBook Pro. I also have Bose wireless headphones. 
If I put my laptop to sleep, and after a while turn on my headphones, the headphones will wake up my laptop. How to prevent this behaviour, while still keeping the option to wake up the laptop with keyboard/mouse/trackpad? Is there a systematic change (other than ie manually disconnecting my headphones every time before I put the laptop to sleep)?

Comment: I must be missing something obvious... If you are turning on your headphones, dont you *want* your computer to turn on?  Why else would you turn on your headphones?

Comment: to use them with my phone, or another computer.

Answer (score 0):

On your Macbook, go to System Preferences >> Bluetooth >> Advanced, and **uncheck** "Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer".

[image]

Comment: As noted above, I still need my trackpad and keyboard to wake the computer.

Comment: @srgb you aren't using a bluetooth keyboard and trackpad, you are using the keyboard and trackpad that is wired to your macbook, no? And for the record - I just tested this on my mac mini WITH my wireless mac keyboard and the keyboard still wakes the computer up, but my beats headphones doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with MacOS Big Sur on 2020 MacBook Pro.
I have bluetooth headphones (MPOW), Bluetooth keyboard (Logitech MX keys for Mac) and a wireless mouse on a nano-usb receiver.
The computer would be waken up by headphones (even if I do not fiddle with them, they seem to eventually send some signal or trying to reconnect, no idea), but not by the keyboard! Which I find an extremely useless default setting.

I have tried unchecking the option Bluetooth -> Bluetooth Preferences -> Advanced -> Uncheck Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer (the only control available at the moment).

This sounds like it is not what is needed, but actually it seems to have disabled waking up from headphones but would still wake up from bluetooth keyboard or wireless mouse.

Unfortunately this specific keyboard also goes to sleep after some time and after it wakes up (by a keypress) it cannot longer wake the computer.